# How can one improving/suggest edits to the Tour page

Tags: support

Is it possible to suggested edits or improvements to the Ask Different [Tour page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)?

If yes, how to do it? Is it directly accessible for edits (just like other Q&A posts) to normal users (non-moderators) or does the changes have to be communicated to the site moderators?

Do elected site moderators have access to the tools to directly edit the Tour page?

Comment: Great question - since this is about the process - please feel free to make a specific recommendation for change if you want to see if there is consensus to make that change in a follow on question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tour is controlled by the site developers and is not amenable to the full editing process that exists for questions and answers other than a few portion. Asking here on meta is the way to get a change made - just that different people would be involved based on what precisely you would like to improve.

- If the changer relates to something that is specific to Ask Different it would be handled here by the normal moderation team (for example - changing the question selection, editing the portions of the text, etc...)
- If the change is to artwork, or font or design - we would have the site moderators join us here to collaborate and issue that change.
- If the change is general to all sites, we would migrate it to the main meta once it was clear exactly what change speak requested.

So, for example - if a specific suggestion to change the text below were asked in a follow-on question - we could make that change together.

> **Ask Different** is a question and answer site for Apple
>   enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run *by you* as part of
>   the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites.
>   With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to useful questions about Apple hardware or software. This
>   site is not a discussion forum or blog or wiki, but if you have a
>   practical question about using Apple products, please join us here to
>   ask a question or answer and share your experience and knowledge.